JFreeChart Ring Chart total in center not breaking into multiple lines
JFreeChart Ring Chart total in center not breaking into multiple lines. Here is what I have tried, and here is my output:

I just want to create a JFreeChart which is used later to convert to BufferedImage.
JFreeChart chartPage = ChartFactory.createRingChart("Incidents", donutDataset, true, true, false);
RingPlot donut = (RingPlot) chartPage.getPlot();

//      donut.setCenterTextMode(CenterTextMode.VALUE);
donut.setCenterTextMode(CenterTextMode.FIXED);
String total = "Total :\\n 450";
//      String total = "\<html\> Total \\n <br> :450 \</html\> ";

//      JLabel totalLabel = new JLabel(total);
donut.setCenterText(total);

I have tried the commented scenarios
have tried the JLabel as well as direct texts.
Any way, it is coming only in single line
I want to have it in multiple lines.

Swing components support limited HTML formatting, but a JFreeChart  is not a Swing component. The RingPlot center text is rendered directly using the TextUtils method drawAlignedString as seen here.

See also this example that illustrates a custom RingPlot.
